# Angular 2 - Ожидание выполнения CanActivate

Tags: javascript, angular2, angular4

Вопрос - есть определенные роуты, определенные с помощью стандартного метода роутинга Angular. В CanActivate я указываю свой guard

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService){ 
}

canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
// here check if this is first time call. If not return 
// simple boolean based on user object from authService
// otherwise:

return this.authService.getAuthenticated.map(user => {
      this.authService.setUser(user);
      return user ? true : false;
})

} }
```

Мне необходимо, чтобы при переходе на url, страница не показывалась, пока не выполнилась операция в CanActivate, т.е. работала не асинхронно, а происходило ожидание результата и уже зависимо от него происходил либо переход, либо возврат на предыдущую страницу.

Как это реализовать?

Comment: какая реализация функции `setUser`?

Answer (score 0):

Какой результат при текущей реализации?
Если функция `authService.getAuthenticated` возвращает Observable, то это вероятная причина того, что canActivate не выполняется.

Answer (score 0):

`canActivate` должен возвращать `Observable` и задерживать переход на страницу. Вот пример кода, который задерживает выполнение перехода на 15 секунд:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
  return Observable.timer(15000).map(() => true);
}
```